# how to print only part of each row that stars with a particular character

Tags: text-processing, awk, grep

I have a file with over 10,000 rows:

```
head samples   
https://genomequebec.mcgill.ca/nanuqMPS/readSetMd5Download/id/192170/type/READ_SET_FASTQ/filename/HI.2613.007.Custom_0022.ED9_SD2A27-1_180_R1.fastq.gz.md5
https://genomequebec.mcgill.ca/nanuqMPS/readSetMd5Download/id/192170/type/READ_SET_FASTQ_PE/filename/HI.2613.007.Custom_0022.ED9_SD2A27-1_180_R2.fastq.gz.md5
https://genomequebec.mcgill.ca/nanuqMPS/readSetMd5Download/id/192171/type/READ_SET_FASTQ/filename/HI.2613.007.Custom_0021.ED4_KS1A29-7_338_R1.fastq.gz.md5
https://genomequebec.mcgill.ca/nanuqMPS/readSetMd5Download/id/192171/type/READ_SET_FASTQ_PE/filename/HI.2613.007.Custom_0021.ED4_KS1A29-7_338_R2.fastq.gz.md5
https://genomequebec.mcgill.ca/nanuqMPS/readSetMd5Download/id/192168/type/READ_SET_FASTQ/filename/HI.2613.007.Index_18.ED17_MO1A26-7_353_R1.fastq.gz.md5
https://genomequebec.mcgill.ca/nanuqMPS/readSetMd5Download/id/192168/type/READ_SET_FASTQ_PE/filename/HI.2613.007.Index_18.ED17_MO1A26-7_353_R2.fastq.gz.md5
https://genomequebec.mcgill.ca/nanuqMPS/readSetMd5Download/id/192169/type/READ_SET_FASTQ/filename/HI.2613.007.Index_14.ED14_IA2A35-2_310_R1.fastq.gz.md5
```

I want to print only part of each line that starts with "HI.*"

This is my desired output:

```
HI.2613.007.Custom_0022.ED9_SD2A27-1_180_R1.fastq.gz
HI.2613.007.Custom_0022.ED9_SD2A27-1_180_R2.fastq.gz
HI.2613.007.Custom_0021.ED4_KS1A29-7_338_R1.fastq.gz
HI.2613.007.Custom_0021.ED4_KS1A29-7_338_R2.fastq.gz
HI.2613.007.Index_18.ED17_MO1A26-7_353_R1.fastq.gz
HI.2613.007.Index_18.ED17_MO1A26-7_353_R2.fastq.gz
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Using `awk`

```
awk -F'/' '$NF ~ /^HI\./{ print $NF }' infile
```

to remove the `.md5` suffix, you could do:

```
awk -F'(/|.md5)' '$(NF-1) ~ /^HI\./{ print $(NF-1) }' infile
```

- in `awk`, the `$0` is referring to the whole line/record and `$1`, `$2`, `$3`, ... are referring to the first, second, third, ... respectively; and `$NF` referring to the last field and accordingly the `$(NF-1)` is the second last field.
- the tild `~` operator in awk treat the right-hand operator as (extended) regular-expression match against the left-hand operand as string `string ~ /regular-expression/`

#### The `sed` solution:

```
sed 's:.*/\([^/]*\)\.md5$:\1: ; /^HI\./!d' infile
```

- this `/\([^/]*\)\.md5` matches last slash followed by anything but not a slash that ends with `.md5`. We take `\([^/]*\)` (everything between last slash and `.md5` as a group match and print just that in replacement part with its back-reference `\1`.
- this `/^HI\./!d` deletes the lines which doesn't start with `HI.` from the result of previous `sed` command.
- we used different `sed` delimiter `:` since we have special `/` character in the input.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
awk -F '/' '$NF ~ /^HI/ {print substr($NF, 1, length($NF)-4)}' file.txt
```

- prints the last field if last field starts with `HI`
- excludes the last 4 charecters `.md5`

Output

```
HI.2613.007.Custom_0022.ED9_SD2A27-1_180_R1.fastq.gz
HI.2613.007.Custom_0022.ED9_SD2A27-1_180_R2.fastq.gz
HI.2613.007.Custom_0021.ED4_KS1A29-7_338_R1.fastq.gz
HI.2613.007.Custom_0021.ED4_KS1A29-7_338_R2.fastq.gz
HI.2613.007.Index_18.ED17_MO1A26-7_353_R1.fastq.gz
HI.2613.007.Index_18.ED17_MO1A26-7_353_R2.fastq.gz
HI.2613.007.Index_14.ED14_IA2A35-2_310_R1.fastq.gz
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F"filename/" '{gsub (".md5","");print $2}'
```